# maths to shift vertices along normal

Tags: 3d

I have some 3D points. For every point, I use near few points to calculate the normal vector of that point. Then I want to move the point 1-unit along the normal vector and find the new 3D coordinate of that point?

What I think is:

1. Use the normal vector as normalized z, then find the normalized y, and z by cross product.
2. If I recalled right, the column of 3x3 rotation matrix is [ normalized x, normalized y, normalized z]?
3. Build a 4x4 matrix. Top 3x3 is the rotation matrix, translation matrix is the point [x,y,z]
4. Then multiply the 4x4 matrix with [ 0 0 1 0] (1 unit along z?)

Thanks in advance for correcting my logic, or propose a better and simpler solution.

(I am using PCL library)

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do with points. Can you, please, give some example.

Comment: change the topic to maths to shift vertices along normal, hope this is clearer. thx

Comment: What if you just added a normal to the point you want to move? There's no point using so many operations here.

Comment: I tried to add normal to the point I want to move, it did not work. I wonder why it did not work. Thx.

Comment: Problem is I wanted to move 1 unit in z direction of the normal vector, which is different axis that the global axis (0, 0, 1). I can find rotation matrix to do so, but should it be an easier way (how to do the addition)? Thanks.

Comment: if the new position is p + n, then (p+n -p) dot n equals to 1. So it should be fine to just do naive addition, but I plotted it in point cloud, the new points are wrong..(become some random clouds)